# How to use a package made for non-framework in Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

## Warning

This might not be the place to ask such questions but I'm looking for guidance. Not exactly a final answer as I can see this question is open-ended.

## Introduction

I have a package developed to listen for clicks, window resizes and many other events from the browser.

## How it works

Whenever I import this package locally in a simple project without any framework (just transpiling from TS to JS) I can use the package normally and everything works:

```js
<script type="module">
  import { DevqalySDK } from '/src/index.ts'
  const devqaly = new DevqalySDK({
    projectKey: '99851ecf-af1e-4e0b-9118-466babf48a3a',
  })

  devqaly.showRecordingButton()
</script>
```

## When I import into a Vue project

Now, when I try to use the package in a starter Vue's application (created with `npx init vue@latest` command):

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import {DevqalySDK} from '@devqaly/browser'
import { onMounted } from "vue";

onMounted(() => {
  const sdk = new DevqalySDK({
    projectKey: 'project-key'
  })

  sdk.showRecordingButton()

  console.log('asd')
})
</script>
```

I get the following error: `ReferenceError: v is not defined`

Upon debugging I have arrived at this part of the code that generates this error:

```js
// sdk.ts
import { writeRecordingScript } from './services/RecordingService'

export class DevqalySDK {
  private async onRecordingStart() {
    const newWindow = window.open()

    if (!newWindow) throw new DevqalyError('Cant create window')

    newWindow.document.write(writeRecordingScript())
  }
}

// RecordingService.ts
export function writeRecordingScript() {
  const code =
    '(' +
    function () {
      class RecordingService {
        stream
        recorder
        dataPromise

        async start() {
          const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()
          this.stream = stream
          const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
            mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9',
          })
          recorder.start()

          this.recorder = recorder

          const channel = new BroadcastChannel('devqaly')

          channel.onmessage = async _e => {
            this.stop()
          }

          this.recorder.ondataavailable = ev => {
            channel.postMessage(ev.data)
            window.close()
          }

          channel.postMessage('started')

          window.onbeforeunload = _e => {
            channel.postMessage('cancel')
          }
        }

        stop() {
          this.recorder.stop()
          this.stream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop())
          return this.dataPromise
        }
      }

      async function main() {
        const recorder = new RecordingService()

        const message = document.createElement('h1')

        try {
          await recorder.start()
          message.innerText =
            'Recording started, go back to your app and leave this tab open! Do not close this tab, closing it will cancel the session.'
        } catch (e) {
          message.innerText = 'User clicked cancel on the recording screen picker'
        }

        document.body.append(message)
      }

      main().catch(console.error)
    } +
    ')'

  return `
  <script>
    ${code}()
  </script>
  <body>
  </body>
  `
}
```

When looking at the generated code in the browser after transpiling I get the following:

```js
    (function() {
    class e {
      constructor() {
        v(this, "stream");
        v(this, "recorder");
        v(this, "dataPromise");
      }
      async start() {
        const i = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
        this.stream = i;
        const o = new MediaRecorder(i, {
          mimeType: "video/webm;codecs=vp9"
        });
        o.start(), this.recorder = o;
        const l = new BroadcastChannel("devqaly");
        l.onmessage = async (f) => {
          this.stop();
        }, this.recorder.ondataavailable = (f) => {
          l.postMessage(f.data), window.close();
        }, l.postMessage("started"), window.onbeforeunload = (f) => {
          l.postMessage("cancel");
        };
      }
      stop() {
        return this.recorder.stop(), this.stream.getTracks().forEach((i) => i.stop()), this.dataPromise;
      }
    }
    async function t() {
      const n = new e(), i = document.createElement("h1");
      try {
        await n.start(), i.innerText = "Recording started, go back to your app and leave this tab open! Do not close this tab, closing it will cancel the session.";
      } catch {
        i.innerText = "User clicked cancel on the recording screen picker";
      }
      document.body.append(i);
    }
    t().catch(console.error);
  })()
```

You can see that the `v` in the constructor is the part that says it's `undefined`.

## Questions

1. Does this error has to do with the fact that when I do `window.open()` I'm getting a reference to the shadow DOM and not the DOM itself? Not really sure if this makes much sense but I'm running out of ideas to debug this issue
2. This question goes beyond this post but I would love any resource to learn more about: how I should structure an SDK that will work for simple projects but also to with other frameworks? The idea here is to be able to work primarily with the DOM and listen to events

## EDIT

*tsconfig.json* for the SDK project

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/services"]
}
```

Comment: It's unknown what was the settings to transpile but it's obvious that it went wrong where v() is used. Either declare class fields dataPromise etc properly with types, or don't declare them at all. window.open can be a problem because of a popup blocker but it's unknown if it's the case. It's irrelevant to the error. I'm not sure what kind of advice is needed for the structure. The lib is supposed to have public api that you need, you can check major third-party libs for some questionable moments, including the ones you already use. Vue itself is the example of such a lib.

Comment: For framework-aware lib it's a good practice to expose the methods to both init and destroy. I assume this wasn't done yet

Comment: @EstusFlask I have updated the question to include my `tsconfig.json` for the package. When I go to the `dist/` folder in my package I search for strings such as `v(` but I can't find anything on it. Is it possible that Vue is re-writing the output of `writeRecordingScript` function?

Comment: @EstusFlask Regarding the structure: we are looking to do something just like Sentry does. You can install the framework agnostic SDK or use a package specificaly to your framework. Are there any articles out there that has some guidance on how to get started with this approach?

Comment: Not aware of any. I don't see many specific things to address. Better to bundle it as both UMD and ESM. es2020 is probably too high for general purpose, could be 2017. The problem is that you investigate minified code, disabling a minifier would make it quicker. useDefineForClassFields is what causes the problem with v, you don't generally need it, remove it. It's expected that class field is transpiled to something like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=7#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7plagvkA , I don't know how Object.defineProperty became v in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Estus Flask suggestions, the solution was to remove `useDefineForClassFields` from my `tsconfig.json`